# confusing behavior of afterUpdate

Tags: svelte

i am confused about when the condition afterUpdate method is called.

here's my code snippet

```html
<script>
import { afterUpdate } from 'svelte'
let value =0
let textValue =''

afterUpdate(() => {
    console.log(`afterupdate`)
    textValue = value.toFixed()
})
</script>

<div>
    <p>{value}</p>
    <button on:click={()=>value=value+1}>
        increase
    </button>
</div>
```

when i clicked the button, i expected the afterUpdate method is called infinitely since the update of textValue inside afterUpdate will trigger the next afterUpdate calls. but the afterUpdate is called only once(which is unexpected but good result) when i clicked the button.

why is that??

Answer (score 0):

The `textValue` variable is not read, so it is not taking part in component invalidation.

Even if it were, invalidation in `afterUpdate` does not trigger another update loop. The same is true for other code; assignments mark the component as dirty, on update additional changes can happen but after that the dirty flag is cleared, so you cannot easily run into loops.